# "Optimizar" inicio al abrir app por primera vez

Tags: android

Tengo un dilema que al iniciar la app la primera vez se queda en una pantalla en blanco por 5 segundos y luego sigue sin problemas, pero esto pasa solo la primera vez que se inicia, después carga de inmediato.

Esta es la siguiente pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que tengo como primer `activity` para mostrar es un `splash`

```
   public class Splash extends Activity {

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },2000);
    }

}
```

¿ Alguna idea para evitar la "pantalla blanca" la primera vez que inicia la app ?

Comment: corta tu imagen es muy largo porfavor.

Comment: Cerraré la pregunta como ya realizada, puedes ver una respuesta de WebServeis y la mia, ahí esta lo que yo realizo para evitar ese "Molesto fondo blanco" y siempre tengas un fondo, saludos!

Comment: Okay gracias !!